# Parse Server: User beforeSave (querying user results in error)

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to migrate my Parse app to Parse Server. I am getting the following error (in `Parse.User.beforeSave`)

> `Received an error with invalid JSON from Parse: Cannot POST /classes/_User`

```
if (user.get('family')) {
    var query = new Parse.Query('_User');
    query.equalTo('family', user.get('family')); // got here ...
    return query.count() // appears to fail here
        .then(function(count) { 
            if (count < 10) {
                return Parse.Promise.as();
            } else {
                return Parse.Promise.error('Family size cannot exceed 10.')
            }
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
            console.log('family size', err.message);
            return Parse.Promise.error(err.message);
        });
}
return Parse.Promise.as();
```

Why might it be trying to POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured I need to add the parse mount point to the `serverURL`. The example app should have done that ...